# How do I change a VMWare 1.x server's guest boot order?

Tags: linux, boot, vmware

I have 4 VMs on a Linux host, call them A, B, C, D running on Z. I really don't care when A and B come up, but I would like to make sure that D comes up before C.

I believe that in VMWare 2.x it's possible to change the boot order. Is this possible in 1.x as well?

Is this done in /etc/vmware/vm-list? I see that there are a number of VMs listed there, including some that have long since been deleted.

Comment: I'm assuming this is VMWare Server you're talking about and not Workstation? Or is it ESX?

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a way to edit the config file directly, I just can't find it.

However, a (tricky) way that always works for me, (unless you are feeling lucky, you may want to disconnect/disable the hard drive first) - press delete rapidly after starting the VM - you can then go in to the BIOS directly and choose what boot order. If you fail, reboot and try again, then reconnect the hard drive after you have set what you want.

I say disconnect the hard drive, just so you can reboot without damaging anything.